# Get dummies for column of literals, with some values without quotation marks

Tags: python, sql, pandas, csv, literals

I have a .csv file downloaded from an SQL database, where column value is a list of strings.

  However some values come **without quotation** marks around them:

```py
  user_id  B                                    value
0      a1  3                          {no_quotations} #no quotation mark ardoun this word
1      a2  4       {"with quotations", no_quotations} #one with quotations, one without
2      a3  1  {"with quotations", "with quotations 2"} #UPDATE quotations have spaces in them.
3      a4  1          {no_quotations, no_quotations2} #2 without quotations marks
4      a6  1                      {"with quotations"} #UPDATE quotations have spaces in them
```

The words are:

- single alphanumeric for no_quotations
- string alphanumeric + spaces between words for "with quotations"

I want convert the column value into a list of dummies. Expected output:
[image]

The values in column value might change in a future iteration, so I don't want the code to depend on the exact string of the value. 
I am able to do this for values **with quotations**, but not for all

```py
import pandas as pd 
import ast 

df = pd.read_csv("/content/SQLDB_quotations_in_literal_example.csv")
df_ = df.iloc[[2,4]]['value'].apply(lambda x: list(ast.literal_eval(x))) 
pd.merge(df, pd.get_dummies(df_.apply(pd.Series).stack()).groupby(level=0).sum(), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer' )

OUT: 

  user_id  B                                     value  with quotations  \
0      a1  3                           {no_quotations}              NaN   
1      a2  4        {"with quotations", no_quotations}              NaN   
2      a3  1  {"with quotations", "with quotations 2"}              1.0   
3      a4  1          {no_quotations, no_quotations_2}              NaN   
4      a6  1                       {"with quotations"}              1.0   

   with quotations 2  
0                NaN  
1                NaN  
2                1.0  
3                NaN  
4                0.0
```

- How do I handle the missing quotation marks around certain strings in col value?
- Since the table was taken from SQL, is this an error in how the SQL table data was stored? or is there a way of downloading the data without this issue?

**EDIT**
Other important info - string "with quotations" have a spaces in them, the no_quotations  have none

Comment: Just to be sure, the words are alphanum/underscore only? If not please clarify so that I update the regex

Comment: @mozway yes, alphanum with underscore

Comment: @mozway sorry, alphanumeric with underscore and space sometimes between the words.. didn't think it was important but just tried it and it wont work. So more like "with quotations" and no_quotations (as in only spaces when there are quotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach with [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```py
out = df.join(df['value']
 .str.extractall('(\w+)')[0]
 .droplevel(1).reset_index(name='col').assign(value=1)
 .pivot_table(index='index', columns='col', values='value', fill_value=0)
)
```

Alternative with [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```py
out = df.join(df['value']
 .str.extractall('(\w+)')[0]
 .groupby(level=0).agg('|'.join).str.get_dummies()
)
```

output:

```
  user_id  B                                    value  no_quotations  no_quotations2  with_quotations  with_quotations2
0      a1  3                          {no_quotations}              1               0                0                 0
1      a2  4       {"with_quotations", no_quotations}              1               0                1                 0
2      a3  1  {"with_quotations", "with_quotations2"}              0               0                1                 1
3      a4  1          {no_quotations, no_quotations2}              1               1                0                 0
4      a6  1                      {"with_quotations"}              0               0                1                 0
```

###### variant: allow spaces inside a word:

Use the following regex: `r'([^",{}]*[^",{}\s])'` in `extractall`.

output:

```
  user_id  B                                     value   no_quotations   no_quotations2  no_quotations  with quotations  with quotations 2
0      a1  3                           {no_quotations}               0                0              1                0                  0
1      a2  4        {"with quotations", no_quotations}               1                0              0                1                  0
2      a3  1  {"with quotations", "with quotations 2"}               0                0              0                1                  1
3      a4  1           {no_quotations, no_quotations2}               0                1              1                0                  0
4      a6  1                       {"with quotations"}               0                0              0                1                  0
```